# Comparing columns of a text file

Tags: go

I need some advice on this piece of code. I'm developing a application in Go to read the content of a file line by line and compare one specific column formed by a hash with others in the same file. I'm trying to catch different hashes to the same filename and get an alert that a file has been changed.

Here's an example of the text file. Each line is formed by filename, hash and computer name:

```
c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe;0f3c97716fed8b554a7ec0464d50719f;computer1
c:\program files (x86)\google\chrome\application\chrome.exe;d387a06cd4bf5fcc1b50c3882f41a44e;computer1
c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe;AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA;computer1
c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe;BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB;computer1
c:\program files (x86)\google\chrome\application\chrome.exe;d387a06cd4bf5fcc1b50c3882f41a44e;computer1
c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe;f60a9d3a9461f68de0fccebb0c6cb31a;computer1
```

When running the code I'm getting the same information twice because I used two for. Obviously I just need one occurrence of each. Results:

```
go run main.go 
Original:   c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe 0f3c97716fed8b554a7ec0464d50719f computer1
Violation:  c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB computer1
------
Original:   c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA computer1
Violation:  c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe f60a9d3a9461f68de0fccebb0c6cb31a computer1
------
Original:   c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB computer1
Violation:  c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe 0f3c97716fed8b554a7ec0464d50719f computer1
------
Original:   c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe f60a9d3a9461f68de0fccebb0c6cb31a computer1
Violation:  c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA computer1
------
IGNORE THIS LINE []
IGNORE THIS LINE []
```

Expected result:

```
c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe;0f3c97716fed8b554a7ec0464d50719f;computer1
c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe;BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB;computer1

c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe;AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA;computer1
c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe;f60a9d3a9461f68de0fccebb0c6cb31a;computer1
```

I tried break, continue, variables, etc but I think that I'm having trouble with logic to report only one occurrence.

Here's the code (finally):

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

const (
    FILE_DIR = "./logs/"
)

func main() {

    p := fmt.Println

    // List and open all log files
    listOfFiles := listDirFiles(FILE_DIR)
    for _, file := range listOfFiles {

        f, err := os.Open(FILE_DIR + file)
        if err != nil {
            p("Error when opening the file " + FILE_DIR + file + " .")
            break
        }
        defer f.Close()

        var lines []string
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            lines = append(lines, scanner.Text()) // Converting the content of a file into a slice
        }

        results := testViolation(lines)
        fmt.Println("IGNORE THIS LINE", results)
    }

}

func testViolation(lines []string) []string {
    var splitLine []string

    for _, f := range lines {
        splitLine = strings.Split(f, ";")

        for _, c := range lines {
            checkLine := strings.Split(c, ";")
            if splitLine[0] == checkLine[0] && splitLine[2] == checkLine[2] && splitLine[1] != checkLine[1] {
                fmt.Println("Original:  ", splitLine[0], splitLine[1], splitLine[2])
                fmt.Println("Violation: ", checkLine[0], checkLine[1], checkLine[2])
                fmt.Println("------")
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func listDirFiles(dir string) []string {

    var filesString []string
    files, _ := ioutil.ReadDir(dir)

    // Convert []os.FileInfo into []string to return
    for _, f := range files {
        filesString = append(filesString, f.Name())
    }
    return filesString
}
```

I really appreciate your help.

Mario.

Answer (score 0):

Use a map[string]string (e.g. mapName[computerName+fileName] = fileHashvalue, for each line check if the map entry exists for the given computer and file name (concatenated string - computerName + fileName) & if so compare with the existing hash value) you can do this in just one range loop instead of two you are using now. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

on testViolation you has (i deleted google chrome entry to better visibility):

```
line0 =
c:\program files\internetexplorer\iexplore.exe;
0f3c97716fed8b554a7ec0464d50719f;
computer1

line1:
c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe;
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA;
computer1

line2:
c:\program files\internetexplorer\iexplore.exe;
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB;
computer1

line3:
c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe;
f60a9d3a9461f68de0fccebb0c6cb31a;
computer1
```

On your loop:

```
for _, f := range lines {
    splitLine = strings.Split(f, ";")

    for _, c := range lines {
    // To f == line0, you match with c == line2
    // To f == line1, you match with c == line3
    // To f == line2, you match with c == line0
    // To f == line3, you match with c == line1
        checkLine := strings.Split(c, ";")
        if splitLine[0] == checkLine[0] && splitLine[2] == checkLine[2] && splitLine[1] != checkLine[1] {
        // ...
        }
    }
}
```

So, you need delete line when you find a match.
it's not very sexy, but it's work

more simply:
I think, you sould build a map["string-untilFirst';'"][]"stringhash+computer" on begin function.

```
// map[string][]string
```

So, just you count number element:

```
for _, v := range myMap {
    if len(v) > 1 {
    // if you need compare computer you can split here or use:
    // map[string]map[string][]string
    // "there are a diff on v[0] and v[1] * len(v)"
    }
}
```

I hope help you ;)
Good continuation on you project !